# The constraint 'IDENTITY' is not supported in a federated database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, federation, sql-azure-federations

When am trying to create a table in federation am getting this error.How can I solve this. I have to use Identity. All things where set. but when try to apply federation this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely need to use guid based keys in a federated DB.

If you think about multiple places generating an integer key, there is a lot of possibility for collision. With federated databases in SQL Azure, you are dealing with the same table split across multiple instances. That is why you cannot have an integer being generated by identity.

Answer (score 2):

You can create bigint columns and use Identity generator like [SnowMaker](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/07/14/released-snowmaker-a-unique-id-generator-for-azure-or-any-other-cloud-hosting-environment/) to generate Unique IDs across the federation. I am using it on one of my project and works very nicely